# Symfony form collection - maintain association with primary key

Tags: symfony-forms, symfony4

I have a Symfony form containing a collection which is defined as follows:

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Documents;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class DocumentsType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add(
            'documents',
            CollectionType::class,
            [
                'entry_type' => DocumentType::class,
                'by_reference' => false,
                'entry_options' => [
                    'label' => false,
                ],
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'delete_empty' => true,
                'attr' => [
                    'class' => 'documents-collection',
                    'data-min-items' => 1,
                ],
                'required' => true,
            ]
        );

        parent::buildForm($builder, $options);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(
            [
                'data_class' => Documents::class,
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

And DocumentType as this:

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Document;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FileType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\HiddenType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class DocumentType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add(
                'description',
                TextType::class,
                [
                    'required' => true,
                    'attr' => [
                        'placeholder' => 'Document description, eg: Ticket, receipt, itinerary, map, etc…',
                    ],
                ]
            )
            ->add(
                'document',
                FileType::class,
                [
                    'mapped' => false,
                    'required' => true,
                ]
            );

        parent::buildForm($builder, $options);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(
            [
                'data_class' => Document::class,
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

The Documents entity is:

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Service\Uuid;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
* @ORM\Entity
*/
class Documents
{
    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="uuid")
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="UUID")
    * @ORM\Id
    */
    private $id;

    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToMany(
    *     targetEntity="Document",
    *     cascade={"persist", "remove"},
    *     orphanRemoval=true
    * )
    * @ORM\JoinTable(
    *     name="documents_document",
    *     joinColumns={
    *         @ORM\JoinColumn(name="documents_id", referencedColumnName="id"),
    *     },
    *     inverseJoinColumns={
    *         @ORM\JoinColumn(name="document_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique=true),
    *     }
    * )
    * @var Document[]
    */
    private $documents;


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->id = Uuid::uuid4();

        $this->documents = new ArrayCollection();
    }


    /**
    * @return mixed
    */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
    * @return Collection
    */
    public function getDocuments(): Collection
    {
        return $this->documents;
    }

    /**
    * @param Document $document
    *
    * @return $this
    */
    public function addDocument(Document $document): Documents
    {
        if (!$this->documents->contains($document)) {
            $this->documents->add($document);
            $document->setDocuments($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
    * @param Document $document
    *
    * @return bool
    */
    public function hasDocument(Document $document): bool
    {
        return $this->documents->contains($document);
    }

    /**
    * @param Document $document
    *
    * @return $this
    */
    public function removeDocument(Document $document): Documents
    {
        if ($this->documents->contains($document)) {
            $this->documents->removeElement($document);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
    * @param Collection $documents
    *
    * @return $this
    */
    public function setDocuments(Collection $documents): Documents
    {
        $this->documents = $documents;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
    * @return $this
    */
    public function clearDocuments(): Documents
    {
        $this->documents = new ArrayCollection();

        return $this;
    }
}
```

And the Document Entity is:

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Service\Uuid;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
* @ORM\Entity
*/
class Document
{
    /**
    * @var Uuid|string
    * @ORM\Column(type="uuid")
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="UUID")
    * @ORM\Id
    */
    private $id;

    /**
    * @var Documents
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Documents")
    */
    private $documents;

    /**
    * @var string
    * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=1024, nullable=false)
    */
    private $description;


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->id = Uuid::uuid4();
    }


    /**
    * @return Uuid|string
    */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
    * @return Documents
    */
    public function getDocuments(): Documents
    {
        return $this->documents;
    }

    /**
    * @param Documents $documents
    *
    * @return $this
    */
    public function setDocuments(Documents $documents): Document
    {
        $this->documents = $documents;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
    * @return string
    */
    public function getDescription(): ?string
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    /**
    * @param string $description
    *
    * @return $this
    */
    public function setDescription(string $description): Document
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

I create the form in my controller like this:

```
$repo = $entityManager->getRepository(Documents::class);
$documents = $repo->findOneBy(['id' => $id]);

$form = $this->formFactory->create(
    DocumentsType::class,
    $documents
);
```

When I add new Document entries to the collection in the rendered form and then save the form, they are correctly persisted to the database and linked to the Documents entity.

If I remove the last entry in the collection, it is correctly removed from the $documents Collection and then deleted from the documents table, as there are no longer any references to it.

However, if I remove an entry in the middle of the collection, Doctrine saves the data from the remaining entries over the deleted one and its followers, and then removes the last entity in the list, changing the ids for all of the entities.

I am saving the file uploaded in the `document` field on `DocumentType` using the UUID as the new filename, so the ids need to stay the same when removing entries from the collection. I have tried adding both a mapped and unmapped id field to the collection, however the unmapped field is ignored entirely, and the mapped field would allow users to modify data in the id column, and thus isn't suitable for use here.

What do I need to do to modify this form to get Doctrine to maintain the connection between the data in the collection and the entity which it represents in the database?

Comment: I might be worthy to add that we are actually using [ninsuo/symfony-collection](https://github.com/ninsuo/symfony-collection) for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after finding [this issue](https://github.com/ninsuo/symfony-collection/issues/85) in the bug tracker of the repo having a similar behavior, [the last linked issue](https://github.com/ninsuo/symfony-collection/issues/109) pointed me to this part of the read me:

> **Do not change field names**
>
> Symfony use field names to order the collection, not the position of
>   each elements on the dom. So by default, if you delete an element in
>   the middle, all following elements will have their index decreased of
>   1 (`field[3]` will become `field[2]` and so on) and if you add some
>   elements in the middle, all subsequent elements will see their index
>   increase to leave the space for the new one.
>
> With this implementation, you're sure to keep the right positions when
>   clicking "move up" and "move down" for exmaple. But in some
>   situations, you may not want to overwrite indexes, most probably to
>   maintain Doctrine relationships.
>
> Set the `preserve_names` option to `true` to never touch field names. But
>   be aware that this option will disable `allow_up`, `allow_down`, `drag_drop`
>   options and will enforce `add_at_the_end` to true.
>
> Default value:
>
> ```
> $('.collection').collection({
>    preserve_names: false
> });
> ```

*source: https://github.com/ninsuo/symfony-collection/blob/d5e6cbc7c7dc1f0509631c9bb6094fead0f6c8f0/README.md#options*

So the solution should be to initialize the collection with the option `preserve_names` set to `true`, rather than the default value, which is `false`.

```
$('.collection').collection({
    preserve_names: true // this is our fix
});
```